# Build GraphQL Query From Mutation Requested Fields

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

It's possible to build a GraphQL query from the mutation requested fields, inside a resolver?

Inside the resolver function, maybe there's a way to reconstruct the requested fields as a GraphQL query using 'info' variable.

Code sample:

```
async actionResolver(parent, args, context, info) {
    // do resolver actions
    .
    .
    .

    const query = buildQueryFromMutationRequestedFields(info); // fn I need to build
    result = await executeQuery(query);

    return result;
}
```